# Update dataframe contents using itertuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
| |st_id|Dep  |Arr   | 
|-|-----|-----|------|
|0|10021|00:15|      |
|1|10022|00:20|00:19 |
|2|10023|00:25|00:24 |
|3|10024|     |00:30 |
```

I need to fill in empty Dep, Arr by condition if Arr =' ' then Arr = Dep if Dep=' 'then Dep=Arr.
I can do it by iterrows like:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[index, 'Arr'] == '':
        df.at[index, 'Arr'] = df.at[index, 'Dep']
    if df.at[index, 'Dep'] == '':
        df.at[index, 'Dep'] = df.at[index, 'Arr']
```

but how to do it with itertuples
I try

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row[3] == '':
        row[3] = row[2]
    if row[2] == '':
        row[2] = row[3]
```

then i have
`TypeError: 'Pandas' object does not support item assignment.`
What is the correct syntax of the assignment?

Comment: Perhaps you want `df.bfill(1).ffill(1)`?

Comment: Thanks, I read the docs, never tried these functions

Comment: Thanks, it works but is 3 times slower on average than iterrows. df.replace('',np.NaN, inplace=True) df.iloc[0]=df.iloc[0].ffill() df.iloc[-1]=df.iloc[-1].bfill() ~9ms